# How to achieve this text shadow in canvas text

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas

```css
textarea
{text-shadow:white 0px 1px 0px, white 0px -1px 0px, white -1px 0px 0px, white 1px 0px 0px, white -1px 1px 0px, white 1px 1px 0px, white -1px -1px 0px, white 1px -1px 0px, white 0px 1.5px 0px, white 0px -1.5px 0px, white -1.5px 0px 0px, white 1.5px 0px 0px, white -1.5px 1.5px 0px, white 1.5px 1.5px 0px, white -1.5px -1.5px 0px, white 1.5px -1.5px 0px, rgb(133, 133, 133) 0px -1px 4px, rgb(133, 133, 133) 0px 3px 4px, rgb(133, 133, 133) 3px 0px 4px, rgb(133, 133, 133) -3px 0px 4px;
color:red;
}
```

```html
<textarea >default text in the textarea
</textarea>
```

How to apply this text shadow in the canvas text. I searched for various ways like this [(http://jsfiddle.net/DirkWeber/nnqc8/1/light/)](http://jsfiddle.net/DirkWeber/nnqc8/1/light/) and I'm not able to replicate this type of text shadow in canvas text. Please let me know how to achieve this.

Comment: Use a mixture of shadowing, fill color, stroke color and stroke width to [approximate your effect](https://jsfiddle.net/r2apkwh0/1/) ... Adjust as needed for font size

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**[Canvas example](https://jsfiddle.net/cnsvnc/vp9tr2od/1/)**

```js
var canvas = document.getElementsByTagName("canvas")[0],
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

ctx.font="75px verdana";
ctx.shadowColor="black";
ctx.shadowBlur=10;
ctx.lineWidth=10;
ctx.strokeStyle = "white";
ctx.strokeText("HELLO",25,100);
ctx.shadowBlur=0;
ctx.fillStyle="red";
ctx.fillText("HELLO",25,100);
```

```html
<canvas id="c" width="300" height="130"></canvas>
```

**CSS example**

```css
.text {font-size: 3em;
  -webkit-text-stroke: 2px white;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: black;
  -webkit-animation: fill 1s infinite alternate;
text-shadow:2px 2px 10px #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="text">default text in the textarea
</div>
```

Comment: Not exactly. But how you will achieve this?

Comment: I can help you clarify what you want to do.